# Why does Artemis feel problem in knowing the textbook reply?

Tags: movie, artemis-fowl

Chief and Artemis are sitting face to face:

> Chief: Now, Artemis, there is a problem.
>
> Artemis: **The problem is that I know the textbook reply** to any question
> you may choose to ask.
>
> Chief: The problem is that you don't respect anyone enough to treat
> them as an equal.

Why does Artemis feel problem in knowing the textbook reply?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, and its been a while since i read the books, but from what i remember about the series, it is most likely him bragging about his intelligence (i have already figured out everything you will ask) and him saying the conversation will be pointless and boring (textbook replies won't reveal anything about him to the chief and he has no interest in the conversation).  So it is more him being condescending i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He thinks he is too smart for school and doesn't feel challenged by any part of the school program because he already knows all the answers he should know on tests and things. As such, it is hard for him to feel respect towards anyone in his school, because he feels like they have nothing to teach him.

Because he is an Unmatched Genius TM. Which, by the portrayal starting from Sherlock Holmes, Gregory House and all other [Insufferable Geniuses](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InsufferableGenius) (warning, tvtropes link) in fiction, means that he has to be a disrespectful jerk with no need for common courtesy.

Because he is an insufferable genius, his own "solution" /analysis of the problem is that "I am too good for the system", not "I am acting like a jerk towards people trying to do their best".

Answer (score 2):

He's too smart and too young to know that being smart ain't enough in life. Equality for instance isn't predicated on intelligence or smarts but on human dignity. He's too young to know what that really means. Most likely he's read it somewhere and probably more than a few times. Most likely he's been told it - like he is being here - before and again more than once, but it hasn't really sunk in - yet.

Eoin is also letting us know, given the chief's swift riposte to Artemis, that knowing textbook answers isn't what schooling/education is all about. It's an authorial comment on why ethics is harder to teach than maths and that Artemis despite his smartass answers still has a lot of growing up to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Chief is pointing out that there is a problem and believes that Artemis' attitude (the belief that he is superior to anyone else) is at the root of the problem.

Artemis is acknowledging that there is a problem, but believes that the problem lies in expectations and predefined roles in society.

He is expected to act/relate like any person his age, but when he proves to be more knowledgable and much more intelligent, adults struggle to relate to him, because they insist on the authority of age and position and refuse to treat him as an intellectual equal or superior.

This is not so much Artemis being taken down a peg for being a jerk (even though he often is) as it is a summary of the premise of the series.

If he is exposed to an environment and individuals who can keep up with or outpace him intellectually, while still taking him seriously despite his age, he would probably be a lot less of an arse. Unfortunately society is inherently ageist, and a young genius is more likely to be told to shut up while the adults are talking than to have their opinions taken seriously.

This issue is what leads to a lot of Artemis' "stupid" decisions and morally borderline behaviour. If adults won't take him seriously when he's talking math/physics/biology/electronics or whatever subject he is clearly their equal or superior in, why should he take them and their opinions seriously about ethics/morality or even life experience?